# lucene solr - how to know numCount of each word in query

Tags: solr, lucene

i have a query string with 5 words. for exmple "cat dog fish bird animals".

i need to know how many matches each word has.

at this point i create 5 queries:

```
/q=name:cat&rows=0&facet=true
/q=name:dog&rows=0&facet=true
/q=name:fish&rows=0&facet=true
/q=name:bird&rows=0&facet=true
/q=name:animals&rows=0&facet=true
```

and get matches count of each word from each query.

but this method takes too many time.

so is there a way to check get numCount of each word with one query?

any help appriciated!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, [functionQueries](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) are your friends. In particular:

> **[termfreq(field,term)](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#termfreq)** returns the number of times the term appears in the field for that document. Example Syntax:
>   termfreq(text,'memory')
>
> **[totaltermfreq(field,term)](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#totaltermfreq)** returns the number of times the term appears in the field in the entire index. ttf is an alias of
>   totaltermfreq. Example Syntax: ttf(text,'memory')

The following query for instance:

```
q=*%3A*&fl=cntOnSummary%3Atermfreq(summary%2C%27hello%27)+cntOnTitle%3Atermfreq(title%2C%27entry%27)+cntOnSource%3Atermfreq(source%2C%27activities%27)&wt=json&indent=true
```

returns the following results:

```
"docs": [
      {
        "id": [
          "id-1"
        ],
        "source": [
          "activities",
          "activities"
        ],
        "title": "Ajones3 Activity Entry 1",
        "summary": "hello hello",
        "cntOnSummary": 2,
        "cntOnTitle": 1,
        "cntOnSource": 1,
        "score": 1
      },
  {
        "id": [
          "id-2"
        ],
        "source": [
          "activities",
          "activities"
        ],
        "title": "Common activity",
        "cntOnSummary": 0,
        "cntOnTitle": 0,
        "cntOnSource": 1,
        "score": 1
      }
}
]
```

Please notice that while it's working well on single value field, it seems that for multivalued fields, the functions consider just the first entry, for instance in the example above, termfreq(source%2C%27activities%27) returns 1 instead of 2.

Comment: well actually i've tried totaltermfreq(field,term) but it must be i've done something wrong. it returns to me "-1" what ever i've been asking. this is the query i create: `q=*:*&fl=ttf(name,"cat"),ttf(name,"dog")&rows=1&wt=json&indent=true` what do i do wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question with an example of output required and I will post the query.

Comment: @SuperYegorius - I added an example of query and results to the answer. Please accept it if you're happy with it.

Comment: thanks! i succed with another field with this query `q=*:*&fl=ttf(kind,"cat"),ttf(kind,"dog")&rows=1&wt=json&indent=true`. the name field has omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" option.